# Android: How to detect which Bluetooth device is currently getting audio stream?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, a2dp

I'm getting a list of A2DP devices like this:

```
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        List<BluetoothDevice> devices = proxy.getConnectedDevices();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {

    }
}, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
```

The problem is that sometimes, when I have more than one device connected, only one of them is getting the audio stream from my app. How can I know which device is the one getting the stream? Also I've heard that in newer Android versions you can be connected to a Bluetooth device but still playing audio in the phone itself, is there a way to know when this happens as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

```
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        List<BluetoothDevice> devices = proxy.getConnectedDevices();
        BluetoothA2dp bA2dp = (BluetoothA2dp) proxy;
        for (BluetoothDevice device: devices) { 
            boolean isPlaying = bA2dp.isA2dpPlaying(device);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {

    }
}, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check here for detail
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major``](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major%60%60) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major

```
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) { String deviceBTMajorClass = getBTMajorDeviceClass(device.getBluetoothClass().getMajorDeviceClass()); if (D) Log.d(TAG, "deviceBTMajorClass"+deviceBTMajorClass); //btArrayAdapter.add(deviceBTName + "\n"+ deviceBTMajorClass); data.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress()); } private String getBTMajorDeviceClass(int major) { switch (major) { case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.AUDIO_VIDEO: return "AUDIO_VIDEO"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.COMPUTER: return "COMPUTER"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.HEALTH: return "HEALTH"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.IMAGING: return "IMAGING"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.MISC: return "MISC"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.NETWORKING: return "NETWORKING"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PERIPHERAL: return "PERIPHERAL"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PHONE: return "PHONE"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.TOY: return "TOY"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.UNCATEGORIZED: return "UNCATEGORIZED"; case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.WEARABLE: return "AUDIO_VIDEO";`enter code here` default: return "unknown!"; } }
```